# passing data in javascript array to server with jQuery.ajax post function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, post

I was wondering if its possible to pass data stored in a javascript array to the server using jQuery's ajax function..

In the jQuery documentation it specifies:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

can "data" be set to an array? How would this work given it seems data is expecting key value pairs? I currently just hard code the values but I want it to be a more dynamic approach..my current code is:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/createtrips/updateitin",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {place1: 'Sydney', place2: 'London'},
            dataType: 'json',
            });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I created an array like this:

```
var placesfortrip = {};
```

then added to it like this:

```
placesfortrip["item"+counter] = inputVal;
```

(where `counter` is an incremented counter variable)
then assigned this to the `data` property of the ajax call

```
 jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/createtrips/updateitin",
            type: 'POST',
            data: placesfortrip,
            dataType: 'json',
            });
```

and if I look at the XHR tab in firebug it appears those values get posted!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) supports the passing of arrays. It simply serializes the array into a name-value string.

> If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key
>   based on the value of the `traditional` setting (described below).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would like to look into using JSON to pass those values.

[This is a good place to start](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Comment: I created an array like this:

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery serialize: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
This produces a standard-looking query string:

a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5
```

Comment: Do you have an example? It doesn't seem to support serialize (?)